# Pass 2d vector to function using object no matching function error

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, vector

I have problem with pass my `vector` to function in object.

Definition of my `vector`

```
class PrintRectangle : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent = 0);

public:
    teacher *tech;
    bool clicked[5][5] = {};
    std::vector<std::vector<perceptron>> p;
}
```

And implementation

```
PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
    p(5, std::vector<perceptron>(5))
{
    tech = new teacher(clicked);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            p[i][j].randweight();
        }
    }
    double learnConst = 0.1;
    tech->learnPerceptrons(p);
}
```

I get an error in `tech->learnPerceptrons(p);`

```
E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'teacher::learnPerceptrons(std::vector<std::vector<perceptron> >&)'
     tech->learnPerceptrons(p);
                             ^
```

My function definition in `teacher` class

```
void learnPerceptrons(std::vector<std::vector<perceptron>> &p)
```

Where is the problem? Should I create object of `teacher` class in diffrent way?

All errors:

```
  ../../Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/printrectangle.cpp: In constructor 'PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget*)':
../../Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/printrectangle.cpp:19:29: error: no matching function for call to 'teacher::learnPerceptrons(std::vector<std::vector<perceptron> >&)'
     tech->learnPerceptrons(p);
                             ^
In file included from E:/Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/printrectangle.h:6:0,
                 from ../../Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/printrectangle.cpp:1:
E:/Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/teacher.h:20:10: note: candidate: void teacher::learnPerceptrons(std::vector<std::vector<teacher::perceptron> >&)
     void learnPerceptrons(std::vector<std::vector<perceptron>> &p);
          ^
E:/Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/teacher.h:20:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::vector<perceptron> >' to 'std::vector<std::vector<teacher::perceptron> >&'
../../Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/printrectangle.cpp:17:12: warning: unused variable 'learnConst' [-Wunused-variable]
     double learnConst = 0.1;
            ^
Makefile.Debug:833: recipe for target 'debug/printrectangle.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/nienazwany/build-nienazwany-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/printrectangle.o] Error 1
```

and all code https://github.com/lukaszog/Perceptron

Comment: Please include the *full* error message, complete and unedited and including informational notes.

Comment: This is a bad-cut snippet (`learnConst`?) post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't using `learnConst`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I put all errors and link do my repo.

Comment: You seem to have multiple `perceptron` class definitions. And a lot of other problems you really should look at.

Comment: Ok, I correct this and updated error log. But still problem with pass vector to function.

Comment: You still haven't fixed the root cause of the error: That you have two (or more?) definitions of the `perceptron` class. One (possibly) global definition, and a separate definition inside the `teacher` class. Those are two distinct and separate classes.

Comment: Ok I find problem. I have `class perceptron;` in `teacher.h` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your post that:

> My function definition in teacher class
>
> void learnPerceptrons(std::vector> &p)

However, your [teacher class on github](https://github.com/lukaszog/Perceptron/blob/master/teacher.h) has a method `void learnPerceptrons(perceptron * (&array)[5][5]);`, not `learnPerceptrons(std::vector<std::vector<perceptron>> &p)`....that must be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The error logs show `perceptron` was also declared in `teacher`:

```
E:/Sieci Neuronowe/Perceptron/teacher.h:20:10: note:   no known conversion for 
argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::vector<perceptron> >' to 'std::vector<std::vector<teacher::perceptron> >&'
```

This `perceptron` was taken in the declaration of `learnPerceptrons()`